# Как изменить src в том div по которому был клик

Tags: jquery

Вот сам код.

```html
<div class="hidvideo">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gfdgd45453443111223fgdf"frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<div class="hidvideo">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/654645dfjkjh887gdf"frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<div class="hidvideo">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gfdgsfsd3dfgdf"frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<div class="hidvideo">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/543534gfdgdfgdf"frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

`.hidvideo` имеет `before` и по нему можно кликнуть, как пре клике на `.hidvideo` взять src фрейма который в нем и изменить его?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.hidvideo').click(function(e){
    $(this).children('iframe').attr('src','НОВОЕ_ЗНАЧЕНИЕ');
});
```